# Simple PL/SQL Stored Procedure Not Functioning Properly Using Select Count(*)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am hoping that someone would be able to help me with my code.

-- This code is supposed to check the database Pages (pname, exit_count(number), entry_count(number)) if a website ('p01') already exists.

-- If the website does exist the code is supposed to return a DBMS message.

--If it does not exist then the website should be added with the pname, exit_count = 0, entry_count = 0.

--The problem is that once I add one website // exec add_pages('p01'); // if I try to add another // exec add_pages('p02'); // I get my DBMS message instead of it adding the website to Pages database.

--Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

--The code has to be in this following format as it is for a school project.

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000 format wrap

create or replace procedure add_pages (
    pname in pages.pname%type)
as
    page_name number;
begin   
select count(*) into page_name from pages
    where pages.pname = pname;
if
    page_name > 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('This Website Already Exists!');
else 
    insert into pages values(pname, 0, 0);

end if;
end;

/
```

Comment: You might try executing `SELECT * FROM PAGES ORDER BY PNAME` just to be certain that you know what exists in the PAGES table before you start. Best of luck.

Comment: Usually it's not a very good idea to give your PL/SQL parameters and variables the names that are the same as table columns.

Answer (score 2):

Don't give parameters names that conflict with columns in tables.

When you have the query

```
select count(*) 
  into page_name 
  from pages
 where pages.pname = pname;
```

You probably mean "compare the value in the `pname` parameter against the value in the `pname` column of the `pages` table".  In actuality, though, `= pname` resolves to the column in the table not to the parameter of the same name.  So your query just ends up counting all the rows in the table where `pname` is not NULL.

You could fully qualify your parameter name

```
select count(*) 
  into page_name 
  from pages
 where pages.pname = add_pages.pname;
```

Most people, though, would adopt a convention to separate parameter names, variable names, and column names.  Personally, I generally use a `p_` prefix for parameters and `l_` for local variables.  But there are many possible naming conventions that avoid the error.

```
create or replace procedure add_pages (
    p_pname in pages.pname%type)
as
    l_page_count number;
begin   
  select count(*) 
    into l_page_name 
    from pages
    where pages.pname = p_pname;

  if l_page_count > 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('This Website Already Exists!');
  else 
    insert into pages values(p_pname, 0, 0);
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help. It was as simple as renaming my value parameter from something else that existed in my table. This worked right away. Awesome job guys!!.